# What is the correct way to deep clone / unbind a object in Vuex

Tags: vuex, action, destructuring, unbind

I'm constantly getting the "[vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers." error on my application. When I use a getter inside a component, I solve it destructuring the getter, something like:

```
const user = {
    ...this.$store.getters["Users/getUser"]
  };
```

But sometimes, when I need to use something of my store state, inside a Vuex action, the only wat to "unbind" the object is using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.something)), because destructuring still returns Vuex mutation error, and using the JSON.stringify and JSON.parse is probably the wrong way:

```
setActiveUser({ commit, state }, payload) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let newUser = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(state.user))

    etc
  });
}
```

What is the correct way to unbind my state?

Thank you.

Comment: I go with lodash's `cloneDeep` for this stuff simply because it will handle all edge cases.

Comment: Sorry, I mistook destructuring by spreading

Comment: lodash's cloneDeep isn't also a "wrong way" to solve this?

Comment: Why do you think it's the wrong way? You ultimately need a copy of the data without having any reference to the original object so you don't mess with the state directly. By definition you need a clone, so how exactly you will escape the "costly" clone function?